# Linq to SQL layers/architecture?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, architecture

I am sorry for my question may looking a old repetitive questions but I as I am starting Linq to SQL I want to discuss how many layers (architecture) should I use ?

I am working on web mostly web sites and small to medium scale web applications. I understand dividing application into layers help its maintainanace and enhancement but frankly I want some balance way which give me rapid development and code reuse-ability as well. I cannot spare so much time on unwanted management of layers.

Before I was using 4 layers (business objects, BLL,DAL and user itnerface.) I became confuse on it as different people have described different layers. Please guide me what and how many layers I should use ? Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I decided to use one layer (DAL + BLL) for small projects and for large applications will use Different layers for DAL & BLL. I will use Linq in DAL and funtiosn will return IQueryable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the layer architecture. Use the [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/).

Answer (score 1):

The most important aspect from architecture perspective is the separation of concerns. Separation of concerns leads to clean code, easy maintenance, extensible, etc. That said, I recommend to base your decisions based on the following criteria:

- Try to architect your system in a loosely coupled way. Use messaging instead of RPC as messaging is reliable, scalable, asychronous, loosely coupled, etc. You can either use MSMQ or NServiceBus (for service bus based architecture).
- Create layers based on the separation of concerns concept. For e.g. you can go for typical 3 layered architecture which will have just UI layer, business logic layer (business rules+workflow) and data access layer or more granular such as UI layer, services layer (facade), business logic layer, data access layer, etc. Using IoC / Dependency injection will make life easy as none of the layers will have direct dependency. Moreover, it promotes unit testing easy as you inject mocks instead of the real implementations for the unit test. There are so many IoC frameworks available (NInject, Autofac, Castle Windsor, Structure Map, etc...)
- Try to use EF instead of Linq to SQL as the later works only with SQL, while the EF works with any database. Moreover, in my opinion, EF is where microsoft is innovating and I would assume that Linq to SQL may be retired one day.

Answer (score 1):

Great question haansi.  This is something that I have wrestled with quite often when building small to medium sized sites.  Finding that balance of creating a architecture that gives you the greatest flexibility and allows for rapid deployment is what I think we all need to strive for in all of our work.

With that being said, I have found that using the [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) to be quite helpful with LINQ to SQL projects.  I couple that with the [Model View Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647543.aspx) pattern (for WebForms or other projects) and it provides a great foundation for reuse with minimal layers.

My Webform calls a Presenter class, which in turn is responsible for populating the View.  To populate that View the Presenter can call N number of Repositories. The Repository is where you encapsulate your DataContext class and your LINQ to SQL calls.  These calls return the model classes.

One huge benefit to this regardless of the size of the app is that get great re-use out of your Repository, you get to maximize the use of LINQ and you have used some patterns that other software developers could easily read and support.

Another big benefit is that you now have created a simple architecture that can benefit from using Unit Testing to test from the Presenter back to the Repository without a ton of effort.

Good luck!